# Getting slow operation for GET /Actuator/Prometheus api

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a spring boot actuator and grafana project but Prometheus execution is very slow and taking around10-15 second, is there any way to execute Prometheus in a millisecond.

**application.properties with below configuration**

```
*management.server.port=1234
management.server.servlet.context-path=/
management.endpoint.web.base-path=actuator
management.endpoint.matrix.enabled=true
management.endpoint.web.exposure.include=health,matrix,Prometheus
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.matrix.export.prometheus.enabled=true*
```